# How can I add taxonomy to uploaded files through an api in Drupal 10

Tags: c#, drupal, drupal-modules

I am trying to add tags to files when they are uploaded to my Drupal site in a structured way, so that they are categorized. The goal is to have the files uploaded and separated into either tag1 or tag2 depending on a dropdown box a user selects from a 3rd party site I have. Also when the files are uploaded I want to be able to separately view the files depending on what tag they are under, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Currently this is my setup on drupal. I have a c# application doing a api post request and attaching a tag through a drop down list, but I mostly want to know how to configure the drupal site correctly.

How can I upload files and apply a tag to them correctly, and view the content on my Drupal site displaying them in their correct tags?
[image: manage fields]

[image: taxonomy terms]

[image: api request post]

[[image: file content structure][2]]